# Writing a method to trigger a job in webapi should be a post or a get call?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

So while writing a controller for my scheduler, I was wondering which is cleaner, should I make a post call to trigger a job? or a get call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `post` is semantically better than `get`, because the concept of a job is to do some processing rather than *getting* something for you.

If your api method intended to just **get/retrieve** some data to the caller, then it wouldn't look like a job at all.

You may also have a *get* and a *post* altogether, where the *post* will do the job, and *get* will return the result of that job.

Answer (score 0):

Typically a Get rest method is to get data.   A Post would be better to trigger a job.